# Left arrows in witharrows package

Tags: witharrows

I wanted to make arrows going down by the left side of the equation when I use the witharrows package because sometimes is to much text on the right side. Sorry that I don't have en image to provide of what I want but I think de description it's enough, but if not I will modify the question adding a picture. Thanks to you all

Comment: Also I might use it frecuently, so if it could be something easy to use in several amd diferent equations that could be great

Comment: And also to have the options of the package like text in the arrows and width of the text and stuff like that. Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @F. Pantigny indicated, this is not built in to `witharrows`, but you can fake it by adding `tikz={bend right, '}` to the `\Arrow` options. The `'` option causes the label to appear on the opposite side of the arrow. The only downside to this solution is that you must manually choose `xoffset=` (with a negative value) to move the arrow and label to the left the correct amount.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}

$\begin{WithArrows}
A & = \bigl((a+b)+1\bigr)^2 \Arrow[jump=2, xoffset=-5cm, tikz={bend right, '}]{we expand} \\
& = (a+b)^2 + 2(a+b) +1 \\
& = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 + 2a + 2b +1
\end{WithArrows}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the package `witharrows`. At this time, it's not possible to draw arrows on the left side of the alignments with `witharrows`. However, it's a good suggestion. I will try to add that feature in `witharrows`.

Comment: Hi, currently I'm having trouble with one system of equations (the size of the equations makes the arrows go of the page but there is space to put the arrows if they where colser to the equations) and I think you better than anyone could help.                                           
                                                                                                                                                  Is there a way to make a  post for you or I should make an other question where I can show the system in code and picture?

Comment: You should post another question on this site with a MWE (minimal working example) showing your problem with the code and the picture of the output. If you want, you can also send me a mail (you will my address on the documentation of `witharrows`).